# Разная длительность анимаций (jQuery animate duration)

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend, animate

Я использую анимированный счетчик, аналогичный этому https://codepen.io/SvetlanaIO/pen/vPBQRy

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы в зависимости от получаемого числа (из html-атрибута data-count) была разная скорость счетчика.

Ниже я примерно написал как может выглядеть функция в duration, но c return у меня ничего не получилось. Подскажите, как правильно передать значение в duration в зависимости от условия и чтобы оно применилось?

```
  $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
        Counter: $(this).attr('data-count')
    }, {
            duration: function () {
                if ($(this).attr('data-count') <= 5) {
                    return 4000;
                } else {
                    return 1000;
                }
            },
            easing: 'swing',
            step: function () {

            },
            complete: function () {

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

duration должен быть числом или строкой, а сейчас вы передаете туда код функции.

В зависимости от условия можно задать так: `duration: условие ? если_верно : если_неверно`

либо передавать вызов функции, а не её код

```
duration: function () {
  if ($(this).attr('data-count') <= 5) {
    return 4000;
  } else {
    return 1000;
  }
}(),
```

```js
$('.counter').each(function() {

  var $this = $(this),
      countTo = $this.attr('data-count');

  $({ countNum: $this.text()}).animate({
    countNum: countTo
  },
  {
    duration: countTo > 150 ? 1000 : 5000,
    easing:'linear',
    step: function() {
      $this.text(Math.floor(this.countNum));
    },
    complete: function() {
      $this.text(this.countNum);
    }
  });  
  
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #F46A6A;
  color:#fff;
  max-width:800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}

.counter {
  display: table-cell;
  margin:1.5%;
  font-size:50px;
  background-color: #FF6F6F;
  width:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height:200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="counter" data-count="150">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="85">0</div>
<div class="counter" data-count="2200">0</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за объяснения.